# Multi-Geo Subscription

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, administration, microsoft-graph

As I'm a Developer and I'm in need of the multi-geo feature to explore them and add these feature in my project.

So please suggest me a way to explore them. Could it be possible without the Enterprise Agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft 365 Multi-Geo is available as an add-on to the following Microsoft 365 subscription plans for *Enterprise Agreement customers*:

- Microsoft 365 F1, F3, E3, or E5
- Office 365 F3, E1, E3, or E5
- Exchange Online Plan 1 or Plan 2
- OneDrive for Business Plan 1 or Plan 2
- SharePoint Online Plan 1 or Plan 2

Check this Microsoft official documentation for more information: [Microsoft 365 Multi-Geo Licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide#licensing)

You can compare all Microsoft 365 Enterprise plans and buy them using below Microsoft official reference:

[Compare all Microsoft 365 Enterprise plans](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans)